# hot reload an es6 module w/o memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, es6-modules

I have a Node server, that I want to hot reload some modules that get sent to the server. Right now I just use a dynamic `await import` and swap out the reference to the module. After the module is loaded though, it stays in the cache forever, and the memory will slowly increase over time whenever it reloads a new version of the module. In practice it's a small amount of memory, but having a memory leak on the server leaves a bad taste in my mouse.

I considered using a worker, but you can't pass functions between threads, and the module I'm needing exposes functions.

I've done some research and so far I can't find any way to do this. Is it possible? I'm expecting the answer is no, and am planning on just restarting the server on reloads and finding some way to make the deploy 0 downtime, but at this point I'm also just curious about the question.

Comment: Is this for development or for production?

Comment: The module should get garbage-collected just fine as soon as nothing references it any longer. Whether that will happen depends a lot on what the module does and how you use it, of course.

Comment: This is for production (though for a personal website). I'm trying to build a mini Google Firebase clone, and want to hot reload new database access rules and "serverless" functions that get deployed to it.

From the research I've done the modules never get garbage collected, even when there's no reference to them (to support the ability to reload them in the future w/o re-running them). Do you have any resources on it getting garbage collected?

Comment: No evidence for my claims, sorry. Can you share the research you've done? Also which module loader are you using?